# exception while reading Excel file with apache poi

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-poi

Problem reading Excel 2007 file .xlsx file extention, while I am trying to read with apache poi:

```
InputStream file = new FileInputStream(C:\\test.xlsx);

---> XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
```

This line giving me an exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject`
please, what can be cause of this error?

Comment: you have not included a library in your class path.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you need to include a jar file named  `xmlbeans-x.x.x.jar` that comes under folder "your_location_of_poi\poi-x.x\ooxml-lib\"  in your classpath.

Note: `x.x` is the version of poi that you are using and `x.x.x` is the version number of that jar file under the above mentioned folder

Comment: you can download that jar file from here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxmlbeansjar.htm by the way. Scroll down for other versions.

Comment: I am using a Linux virtual machine where Office is not installed. I have created a Swing Application for Excel reading. The app works fine in Windows but giving java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException on Linux VM.

Answer (score 2):

You download extra jar file. You can download :

http://www.findjar.com/index.x;jsessionid=D9C61BD4B98370C199118B8C53CC689F?query=org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the extra jar files that come with POI.  Include them in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have XMLBeans in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded xmlbeans.jar and added to Library as External Jar. It resolved my issue.