# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject Error

Tags: java

I am getting following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject
>       at OrderBook.WriteToExcelSheet.CreateOutPutFile(WriteToExcelSheet.java:20)
>       at OrderBook.MainMethod.main(MainMethod.java:71)

I looked for the reasons for this error online but couldn't find why I am getting it.

I have included the following jar files

```
poi-3.9-20121203.jar, 
poi-excelant-3.9-20121203.jar,
poi-examples-3.9-20121203.jar,
poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar,
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar,
poi-scratchpad-3.9-20121203.jar
```

Code:

```
public class WriteToExcelSheet {
    public static Map < Integer, Object[] > data = new TreeMap < Integer, Object[] > ();
    public static void CreateOutPutFile() {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Orderbook Stats");
        //This data needs to be written (Object[])
        //Iterate over data and write to sheet
        Set < Integer > keyset = data.keySet()
        int rownum = 0;
        for (Integer key: keyset) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
            Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
            int cellnum = 0;
            for (Object obj: objArr) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                if (obj instanceof String) cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
                else if (obj instanceof Integer) cell.setCellValue((Integer) obj);
            }
        }
        try {
            //Write the workbook in file system
            System.out.println("OutPutStats.xlsx writing..............................");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("FileLocation/o.xlxs"));
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("OutPutStats.xlsx written successfully on disk.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You have to include one more jar.

```
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
```

Add this and try.

**Note:** It is required for the files with .xlsx formats only, not for just .xls formats.

Comment: @user2942227 you can download it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxmlbeans230jar.htm)

Comment: Now it threw this error,Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentExceptionCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException, Do you know why?

Comment: @user2942227 add dom4j-1.6.1.jar , download it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/d/Downloaddom4j16jar.htm)

Comment: Look for an folder named `ooxml-lib` in the POI archive that you downloaded.

Comment: i had added both jars then also its giving same error

Comment: @asiya can you list all the jars that you added??

Comment: thanks..i resolved it..i was running jar file instead of project

Comment: I just want to add that the Jars are included with the POI Jars. Please take a look at this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046953/exception-while-reading-excel-file-with-apache-poi/13047044#13047044 It helped me so much!

Comment: Thank you :-). It gave me an exception for org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap which was resolved by adding common-collections4-4.1.jar

Answer (score 4):

you have to include two more jar files.

xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar and dom4j-1.6.1.jar 
Add try it will work.

Note: It is required for the files with .xlsx formats only, not for just .xlt formats.

Answer (score 3):

When trying to translate Excel file with .xlsx suffix, you need to add additional jar, xmlbeansxxx.jar. *xxxx*  is version, such as `xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar`

Comment: It fixed that error. Now, it threwNow it threw this error,Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentExceptionCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException, Do you know why?

Comment: You need to add dom4j.jar as well. Since some XML file in POI uses dom4j to handle XML file.

Comment: When you downloads src or bin for POI, there should be a folder named lib. all of the dependency libs, such as xmlBeans and dom4j. jar are thers.

Answer (score 1):

For all that you add xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar and it is not working,you must use HSSFWorkbook instead of XSSFWorkbook after add jar.For instance;

```
    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet listSheet = workbook.createSheet("Kişi Listesi");

    int rowIndex = 0;
    for (KayitParam kp : kayitList) {
        Row row = listSheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
        int cellIndex = 0;
        row.createCell(cellIndex++).setCellValue(kp.getAd());
        row.createCell(cellIndex++).setCellValue(kp.getSoyad());
        row.createCell(cellIndex++).setCellValue(kp.getEposta());
        row.createCell(cellIndex++).setCellValue(kp.getCinsiyet());
        row.createCell(cellIndex++).setCellValue(kp.getDogumtarihi());
        row.createCell(cellIndex++).setCellValue(kp.getTahsil());
    }

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        workbook.write(baos);
        AMedia amedia = new AMedia("Kisiler.xls", "xls",
                "application/file", baos.toByteArray());
        Filedownload.save(amedia);
        baos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include xmlbeans-xxx.jar and if you have downloaded the POI binary zip, you will get the xmlbeans-xxx.jar in ooxml-lib folder (eg: \poi-3.11\ooxml-lib)

This jar is used for XML binding which is applicable for .xlsx files.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar situation, so i replaced all the external jar files(`poi-bin-3.17-20170915`) and make sure you add other `jar` files present in lib and `ooxml-lib` folders.

Hope this helps!!!:)

Answer (score 0):

I was working with talend V7.3.1 and I had poi version "4.1.0" and including xml-beans from the list of dependencies didnt fix my problem (i.e: 2.3.0 and 2.6.0).

```
It was fixed by downloading the jar "xmlbeans-3.0.1.jar" and adding it to the project
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If to do this right way, you need to create a maven project and put all depenencies into `pom.xml` file, dependencies for maven you can google, for example:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/5.0.0?

If to do this hardcore way, download POI library binary files and add all the `.jar` files from all of the folders (for POI 5.0.0) this is (auxiliary, ooxml-lib, lib) folders and root catalog. In my case it works, if you don't want to figure out what library relate for what.

Something like that:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

ClassNotFoundException is thrown when the class is not found in the classpath.
Adding the following jar(contains the definition of the XmlObject interface) will solve the problem

```
xmlbeans-x.y.z.jar
```

You can download the latest xmlbeans jar file at the following link
https://xmlbeans.apache.org/download/index.html

If you are working with the apache poi library make sure you add jars in the lib and ooxml-lib folders.

Comment: @TammaliDeppak the accepted answers 7 years ago was to add a single specific missing JAR  - adding all the JARs while it might work doesn't seem to add new thought to the problem.  Please feel free to update your answer with a new insight.

Comment: @MrR I had the same problem while I was working with the apache poi library. I found that that I did not add the jar files that are present in the lib and ooxml-lib folders. Adding all dependency jars helped. Though as you said I should have given a thought while writing the post, It didn't convey the right information. Thanks :).