# Getting error while reading xlsx file through apche poi

Tags: java, excel, apache, jar

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Exx {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\eXCEL.xlsx"));

    //WorkbookFactory wrk1 =  WorkbookFactory.create(fis)

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);

    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    Iterator ite = sheet.rowIterator();

    while(ite.hasNext()){

        Row row = (Row) ite.next();

        Iterator<Cell> cite = row.cellIterator();

        while(cite.hasNext()){

            Cell c = cite.next();

            System.out.print(c.toString() +"  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    fis.close();
  }
}
```

This is my source code.
JAR Files used are

- poi-3.10-FINAL.jar
- poi-examples-3.10.jar
- poi-excelant-3.10.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.10.jar
- poi-scratchpad-3.10-final.jar
- xmlbean-2.3.0.jar
- dom4j1.6 jar

while running getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject
at Exx.main(Exx.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
```

Please help to sort it out. I tried all beans and all, yet also getting error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739026/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-xmlbeans-xmlobject-error)

Comment: Here's solution to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/19739056/1935341

Comment: i did all the essential jar.buld also.but yet also got the same error

Answer (score 0):

The code runs fine if the below jars are included in the classpath:

- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- poi-3.10-FINAL.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL.jar
- poi.ooxml-schemas-3.10-FINAL.jar
- xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar