# Not able to read excel using Apache POI throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

**Below attached is the code for reading the Excel file using POI** As a beginner need help

```
package genericReusable;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelReader 
{

        public String[] readExcel(String filePath,String fileName,String sheetName) throws IOException
        {

                    //Create a object of File class to open xlsx file
                        File file =    new File(filePath);//new File(filePath+"\\"+fileName);

                    //Create an object of FileInputStream class to read excel file
                        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);


                        Workbook wrkbk = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

                        //Read sheet inside the workbook by its name
                        Sheet sheet = wrkbk.getSheet(sheetName);

                        //Find number of rows in excel file
                        int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum();

                        // Array list to Store the Data
                        ArrayList<String> Data_Array = new ArrayList<String>( );

                        //Create a loop over all the rows of excel file to read it
                        for (int i = 1; i < rowCount+1; i++) 
                        {
                            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);

                            //Create a loop to print cell values in a row
                            for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) 
                            {

                            //Print excel data in console
                            System.out.print(row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+"|| ");

                            Data_Array.add(row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue());

                            }

                            System.out.println();

                        }

                        return (String[]) Data_Array.toArray( new String[ Data_Array.size() ] );

        }




public static void main(String...strings) throws IOException

{


ExcelReader obj = new ExcelReader();
String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\genericReusable";


obj.readExcel(filePath,"ExportExcel.xlsx","Login");

}
}
```

**Running the code displays the below error. Not sure why there is NoClassDefFoundError as i have placed the file in the proper location**
Need Help on passing the excel and reading using Apache POI

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject
at genericReusable.ExcelReader.readExcel(ExcelReader.java:26)
at genericReusable.ExcelReader.main(ExcelReader.java:73)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:    org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 2 more
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: @mrfreester Updated the result.. Still the error displayed

Comment: I'm asking about the line that is throwing the error. For example, is `System.out.println();` throwing the error? Is it `Workbook wrkbk = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);` etc... Please do as much debugging as possible to help people narrow down what could be going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: As for this specific error, look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19739056/1183506)

Comment: It was error due to missing jar file collections4.1

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, it isn't able to find the dependent class which is being used in the project.

You have to add the `XmlBeans` dependency in your project. Add it and the error will go.

You can download the `jar` from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/2.4.0).