# ConditionalFormatting Custom Colors in Apache POI XSSF

Tags: java, excel, apache, colors, xssf

I am trying to set a custom color to fill a row using ConditionalFormatting in an XSSF sheet.

I've tried

```
SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
ConditionalFormattingRule rule1 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("MOD(ROW(),2)=0");
PatternFormatting fill1 = rule1.createPatternFormatting();
XSSFColor customColor = new XSSFColor(new byte[] {alpha, red, green, blue});


fill1.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(128, 0, 128))); //1
fill1.setFillForegroundColor(customColor); //2
```

And neither of those two work. It doesn't accept an XSSFColor.

I saw this [Bug Report](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56774) and tried both "hacks" listed there as working, and again, neither work. Also [the doc](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CustomColors) was no help.

I understand that doing:

```
setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(red,green,blue)));
```

May work for a single cell.

Most solutions I have come across are a few years old and seem not to be working. I just need a away to be able to enter a custom RGB or Hex color as a 
ConditionalFormatting in an XSSF sheet.

Any help?

Also I am running POI 3.9 to avoid parsing errors like:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046953/exception-while-reading-excel-file-with-apache-poi/13047044#13047044) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580826/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-illegalaccesserror).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just created a `for loop` to create a new rule for each color (`short`). It phased out around `62` with a few different shades from there to `80`.
Not exactly custom but at least I can attach the colors to a number.